# Is it possible to configure HtmlPurifer to strip tags that have an attribute with a specific value?

Tags: php, htmlpurifier

I am using HtmlPurifer to sanitize html input.

Here is my HtmlPurifer config:

```
        $config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
        $config->set('Core.Encoding', 'UTF-8'); 
        $config->set('HTML.Doctype', 'XHTML 1.0 Transitional'); 
        $config->set('HTML.AllowedAttributes', "*.style,a.href,a.target,img.src,img.height,img.width");
        $config->set('HTML.AllowedElements','a,p,ol,li,ul,b,u,strike,br,span,img,div');
        $config->set('HTML.ForbiddenAttributes', "*@class,div@*");
        $config->set('Attr.AllowedFrameTargets', array('_blank'));
        $config->set('CSS.AllowedProperties', array('text-decoration', 'font-weight', 'font-style'));
        $config->set('AutoFormat.RemoveSpansWithoutAttributes', true);
        $config->set('AutoFormat.RemoveEmpty', true);
        $purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
        $sanitized = $purifier->purify($data);
```

Works like a charm.

BUT...

I am wondering if it is possible to configure HtmlPurifer such that it will strip any element that does not have an attribute with a SPECIFIC value.

For example, I might want to remove

```
<p class="badParagraph" />
```

but not

```
<p class="goodParagraph" />
```

Does anyone know if this is possible and, if so, how to go about it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned in the corresponding HTML Purifier thread, there is not presently an easy way of doing this. Injectors are a fairly general mechanism by which you could implement this; in which case look at RemoveEmpty for some inspiration.